# separating comma separated value in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

The SP takes the input value ListType_IDs which is a comma separated value of list types.

```
create procedure test
@ListType_IDs varchar(255) = null
as
declare @IsGetDirectReports bit
declare @IsGetDirectReportsManagers bit
declare @IsGetAllManagers bit
declare @IsGetFullTeamUnderManager bit
--I have to initialize the above flags based on the value of list type IDs
```

For example, let ListType_IDs=5,6,7

@IsGetDirectReports = 1, if @ListType_IDs has the value 5

@IsGetDirectReportsManagers = 1, if @ListType_IDs has the value 6

@IsGetFullTeamUnderManager = 1, if @ListType_IDs has the value 7

I need to achieve it using simple SQL code. Anybody please help out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why have you tagged Sql-Server 2005 **and** 2008?  However, there are already many questions regarding this on SO. http://tinyurl.com/by4rst7

Comment: Why not pass to the SP 4  bit values​​?

Comment: Is that a typo?  Should it be value 5 on all three assignments?

Comment: @freefaller : sorry i have wrongly entered the values...it will be 5,6,7...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF CHARINDEX(',5,' , ',' +@ListType_IDs + ',') > 0
SELECT @IsGetIderctReports = 1

IF CHARINDEX(',6,' , ',' +@ListType_IDs + ',') > 0
SELECT @IsGetDirectReportsManagers = 1

IF CHARINDEX(',7,' , ',' +@ListType_IDs + ',') > 0
SELECT @IsGetFullTeamUnderManager = 1
```

[Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad) Now we know.